# Safe number of related entries – before performance hindered?

Tags: entries-field

Is there a safe limit to the number of entries related to another entry via the entry field (including nesting 2 deep) before putting too much strain on  performance? I'm approaching a products range using the entry field, e.g.

```
Parent
-child
-child
-child parent
-- child
-- child
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer, as with most performance related questions is, "it depends".

That's based on environmental factors like how much resources does your site and database have, what else the templates are doing, how are the servers configured, etc.

Craft 2 limits the amount of elements returned in a query to 100 by default, so that would probably be a good place to start.